# How do I correctly require files in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, blockchain

I'm setting up a blockchain client-server network with NodeJS and ExpressJS. I have the server running successfully and the blockchain functioning by itself. But I'm having some problems combining the two. Firstly, here is my project structure:

```
node_p2p/
  node_modules/
    ...
  public/
    block.js
    client.js
    index.html
  package-lock.json
  package.json
  server.js
```

The actual problem that I have is, I want to include `block.js` in the `client.js` file, but I always get `ReferenceError: require is not defined` on the line, where I include `block.js` into `client.js`:

```
var block = require('./block.js');
```

I have already tried the following variations, but all of them produce the same error (quite expected, since require directory is relative to the file calling require, but I tried them anyway, just in case):

```
var block = require('../public/block.js');
var block = require('../public/block');
var block = require('./public/block.js');
var block = require('./public/block');
var block = require('/public/block.js');
var block = require('/public/block');
var block = require('../block.js');
var block = require('../block');
var block = require('./block.js');
var block = require('./block');
var block = require('block.js');
var block = require('block');
```

Here's the code of `block.js`:

```
const SHA256 = require ('crypto-js/sha256');

class Block{
   constructor(...){...}
   ...
}

class Blockhain{
   constructor(...){...}
   ...
}

module.exports = {
  Blockchain: function(){
    return new Blockchain();
  }
}
```

Secondly, `client.js`:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
var block = require('./block.js');

socket.on('client', showData);
socket.on('clientno', showData);
socket.on('newclient', showData);
function showData(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

var nascoin = new block.Blockchain();
```

And finally, `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("server running!");

var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

var client_counter = 0;

function newConnection(socket) {
  console.log('new conn: ' + socket.id);
  client_counter++;

  socket.emit('client', 'your client name: ' + socket.id);
  socket.emit('clientno', 'you are client no.: ' + client_counter);
  socket.broadcast.emit('newclient', 'new client has joined the fray');
  socket.on('server', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

I don't even know what else I can do, either I'm just that dumb or that blind...

Comment: It seems your `client.js` is run inside a browser, so you might want to look into [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or use something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/). `require()` is a NodeJS function and not included in all JS environments.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get,

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

has nothing to do with the actual module you're trying to load not being available. It means the function `require` isn't available at all, just like you'd be calling any old function that's not defined.

```
> require('./pkdxfjdghbdhfksdh')
Error: Cannot find module './pkdxfjdghbdhfksdh'
```

would be what you'd get (in Node) if `require` can't find a module.

How exactly are you running this code? If you're actually running it in Node, e.g. `node client.js`, this error shouldn't occur. If you're attempting to run things in the browser, you will need a bundler like Webpack or Parcel.

Comment: I'm running my server with ```node server.js```, but I have the ```public/client.js``` included in ```public/index.html```, which has been running just fine up until I added the ```var block = require('./block.js');``` line.

Comment: Right. `require` does not exist in browsers – you'll need a bundler. https://parceljs.org/ is arguably the easiest to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you use `client.js`, which attached to `index.html`, just in browser. I recommend you to bundle you `client.js` code with any bundler, `webpack` for example. It will bild browser-compatible code, that you can use in `index.html`.
Browsers haven't `require` built in implementations.